# how to count the frequency of digits exist in a column csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I wanted to count the number of digits exist in a column of my CSV file. For now these are my codes. I am able to get the digits that is in the rows, but i only wanted to know if there are digits in each rows, if yes return 1, else 0. And to also count how many numbers exist in the row.

```
news=pd.read_csv("news.csv")

news['numbers']= news['STORY'].str.extract(r'([\d:]+)') //this gives the digits itself
```

Sample of my news.csv

```
ID      STORY
 1       The theme underlined 3 key messages. 1 of it is..
 2       14th February is a Valentines Day
 3       Today is Monday
```

The output i wanted

```
ID      STORY                                               existnumbers     howmanynumbers
 1       The theme underlined 3 key messages. 1 of it is..     1                 2
 2       14th February is a Valentines Day                     1                 1
 3       Today is Monday                                       0                 0
```

Comment: `existnumbers` would be clearer as a boolean column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html). It could be accomplished like this:

```
news["howmany"] = news["STORY"].str.count(r"\d+")
news["existnumbers"] = news["howmany"] != 0
```

Note that `existnumbers` here would be a boolean field, with `True` indicating that at least one number was found in the `STORY` string. If you wanted an integer field, you could convert as follows:

```
news["existnumbers"] = news["existnumbers"].astype(int)
```

To match non-integers as a single digit, you could use:

```
news["howmany"] = news["STORY"].str.count(r"\d+(\.\d+)?")
```

Comment: .str.count counts each digits, i wanted for e.g. In 2012 there were...., to only be 1 digit

Comment: I have updated the regular expression - this will count 2012 as a single number in your string.

Comment: is it possible for e.g: 10.1 percent...., to only be 1 digit as well?

Comment: Yes, you could change the regular expression to use `\d+(\.\d+)?`, which optionally matches a decimal point and further digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


data = StringIO("""
id  STORY
1  The theme underlined 2013 key messages. 1 of it is
2  14th February is a Valentines Day
3  Today is Monday
""")


df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='  ', engine='python')

df['howmanynumbers'] = df['STORY'].str.count('(\d+)')
df['existnumbers'] = df['howmanynumbers'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0)
```

**Output:**

```
   id                                              STORY  howmanynumbers  existnumbers
0   1  The theme underlined 2013 key messages. 1 of i...               2             1
1   2                  14th February is a Valentines Day               1             1
2   3                                    Today is Monday               0             0
```

Comment: I would avoid using `apply` unnecessarily - it's preferred to use a more efficient, vectorized operation.